# If $a_{n} \to l$, $b_{n} \to l'$ are convergent sequences and $a_{n} \leq b_{n}$, then $l \leq l'$ - Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I'm aware that there are various solutions to this question available, but I wanted to see if my version actually is sound as well.

**Claim:** If $a_{n} \to l$, $b_{n} \to l'$ are convergent sequences and $a_{n} \leq b_{n}$, then $l \leq l'$

**Attempt:**

Towards contradiction, suppose $l' \leq l$. Given that $a_{n} \to l$, $b_{n} \to l'$, then there exists $N_{a} > 0$ and $N_{b} > 0$ such that if $n > max(N_{a},N_{b})$ :

$$|a_{n} - l| < \epsilon\ \text{and}\ |b_{n} - l'|< \epsilon$$

This means:

$$1)\ l-\epsilon < a_{n} < l + \epsilon \\ 2)\ l'- \epsilon < b_{n} < l' + \epsilon$$

If we subtract $2)$ from $1)$ we get:

$$ l - l' < a_{n} - b_{n} < l - l' \\ 0 < l - l' < a_{n} - b_{n} \\ b_{n} < a_{n}$$

If we instead subtract $1$ from $2)$:

$$ l' - l < b_{n} - a_{n} < l' - l \\   a_{n} - b_{n} < l'-l < 0 \\ b_{n} < a_{n}$$

In either case we have shown that $b_{n} < a_{n}$ which contradicts one of our original assumptions. I did notice I didn't use the $\epsilon$ directly in my argument like other proofs I've seen. Is it absolutely necessary that it is used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
\begin{align}
l-\epsilon<a_n<l+\epsilon \\
l'-\epsilon<b_n<l'+\epsilon,
\end{align}
you cannot subtract inequalities have them remain. However, if you multiply the second one by $(-1)$, the system becomes
\begin{align}
l-\epsilon&<a_n<l+\epsilon \\
-l'-\epsilon&<-b_n<-l'+\epsilon.
\end{align}
Adding the inequalities yields
$$
l-l'-2\epsilon<a_n-b_n<l-l'+2\epsilon
$$
Can you arrive at a contradiction if we assume $l>l'$? Hint: Choose $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small.

Comment: I'm not fully sure if this works, but if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, then $0 < l - l' - 2\epsilon < a_{n} - b_{n}$ would still hold and I could just bring the $b_{n}$ over to the other side?

Comment: That's where the contradiction is.

Comment: you mentioned that you cannot subtract inequalities. I don't think I've ever heard that before. How come?

Comment: Here's some intuition. Say $a<b$ and $c<d$.  Then by adding the inequalities, the "less thans" stay aligned so  $a+c<b+d$ makes sense. However, if we subtract the second one, it's really like adding the negative version. The negative version is $-c>-d$. So, it doesn't really make sense to combine the $a$ and $-c$ and arrive at anything meaningful.